# How to use a function to all list in R?

Tags: r

I am not an expert using lapply, apply, etc. So, what I have is the next list

```
my_list
[[1]]
[1] "40.394081 -3.7083041"

[[2]]
[1] "40.3960251 -3.7116921"

[[3]]
[1] "40.3938449 -3.7071731"

[[4]]
[1] "40.3935099 -3.7121505"
```

And I want to use the function `as.numeric` to each entrance of `my_list`. I mean, convert to numeric each entrance of the list but mantaining the structure of list.

Thanks.

Comment: Going by your other questions, is this list the result of a query to Google's API through `googleway` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `lapply` for this:

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) as.numeric(strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]]))
```

Here I use `strsplit` to split the string, just before casting it to numeric using `as.numeric`. `lapply` applies this to each element of your list and returns the result.

Comment: Sorry, but It returns NA's. I think it is because each entrance of a list is not a vector

Comment: Sorry, had not spotted the fact that it was a single string. Expanded my answer.

Comment: It is ok, but needs a parenthesis at the end. Please modifiy it and I will put the answer good

Comment: @HenryNavarro check!

Answer (score 5):

We can use `scan`

```
my_list2 <- lapply(my_list, function(x) scan(text=x, what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE))
str(my_list2)
#List of 4
#  $ : num [1:2] 40.39 -3.71
#  $ : num [1:2] 40.4 -3.71
#  $ : num [1:2] 40.39 -3.71
#  $ : num [1:2] 40.39 -3.71
```

---

It is not clear whether this should be stored as a `list` or not.  If it can be stored as a `data.frame`, a better option would be `unlist` and use `read.table` to create a two column `data.frame`

```
read.table(text=unlist(my_list), header = FALSE)
```

Comment: Scan probably works more robust than my solution using `strsplit`.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra  I think `strsplit` should be fast